# Django: difference between ForeignKey and ManyToManyField

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I seem to have confusion about Django's ForeignKey and ManyToManyField. Supposing I have the following two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
```

A paper may have several authors. I may do either of the followings:

a) Add an `authors` field in `Paper` and add authors to a `Paper` instance:

```
    authors = models.ManyToManyFields(Author)
```

b) Or, I can create another model which contains the authors of a paper:

```
class PaperAuthor(models.Model):
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Which of the above two is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are exactly equivalent. A ManyToManyField automatically creates that "through" table for you; the only difference is that it gives you the ability to access all authors for a paper, or all papers for an author, with a single expression.

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL level,

Django creates a separate table for the many-to-many Field.

```
class PaperAuthor(models.Model):
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

tablename : app_paperauthor

select * from app_paperauthor;

| id | paper_id | author_id |
| 1  | 1        | 1         |
| 2  | 2        | 2         |
```

and the many-to-many field creates a table like below.

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

tablename : app_paper_authors

select * from app_paper_authors;

| id | paper_id | author_id   |
| 1  | 1        | 1           |
| 2  | 1        | 2           |
```

so the difference is the name of the table **app_paperauthor** and **app_paper_authors**.